# LDAP query that returns the groups and parent groups

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I don't understand LDAP in depth, but I'm trying to fix an issue with a PHP application, and I figured that what I need is a query that will return both the groups in which a user is in, and the parent groups of those groups. So if the user is in group A, and group B is a parent group of A, then I need a query that will return both A and B. Is it possible? Does it even make sense? Of course I've searched and tried but I haven't found the answer yet. I know it has something to do with the matching rule "1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941", but I can't figure out how to construct the query.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are right, it has some thing to do with that [matching rule](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups).

(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET))

-jim

Comment: This rule is explicitly marked as ActiveDirectory related query. So when it's not an ActiveDirectory-Backend you probably won't have much luck with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the query returns an error. I'm not sure though if UserName should be replaced by the username of the user logging in, or if it's a keyword that should be left untouched. Could you clarify this for me, please? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, what does Users mean in this context? Could you explain the query a little, so that I may debug more effectively? Thanks, thanks, thanks!